# Eclipse/Android error: String types not allowed

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an options_menu.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="@string/search_title"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
      android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

When I do a project -> clean or a build, I get an error:

> String types not allowed (at 'showAsAction' with value 'collapseActionView|ifRoom')

I cannot figure out what is wrong.  My target SDK version is 11.  Does anybody know what is causing this?

Thanks,
Igor

Comment: I should also add that I get an error like this: "W/ResourceType( 5436): Bad XML block: no root element node found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own issue.  According to the docs, **collapseActionView** was introduced in API level 14.  So I just had to change my target SDK version.  More here: [Menu Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)

Answer (score 5):

Remove **collapseActionView** It is introduced from Api Level 14 and your level is 11.Remove it try.hope it will work.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) you can check it.